# how to build masonry effect like ebay?(Details Inside)

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I've created a masonry effect using the following css,

```
    #wrapper {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1100px;
min-width: 800px;
margin: 10px auto;
}

#columns {
-webkit-column-count: auto;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
-webkit-column-fill: balance;
-moz-column-count: auto;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
-moz-column-fill: balance;
column-count: auto;
column-gap: 15px;
column-fill: balance;
}

.pin {
width: 180px;
display: inline-block;
background: #FEFEFE;
border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
margin: 0 2px 15px;
margin-bottom: 1.875em; /* 15px 30px */
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
-moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
column-break-inside: avoid;
padding: 15px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
-moz-transition: all .2s ease;
-o-transition: all .2s ease;
transition: all .2s ease;
}



<div id="wrapper">
<div id="columns">
<div class="pin">
</div>
<div class="pin">
</div>
.
.
.
.
<div class="pin">
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

it actually works but, it is not so smooth, and misplaces while loading more columns. if you see the ebay.com it won't change the position of the pin, while items are loading onscroll.

would somebody tell me how to achieve that.

Comment: can you please provide the jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm also trying but not getting the proper visual as like as eBay. it keeps on changing while loading.